# Java SSL Handshake failing sometimes fails depending on VM arguments/properties

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have a simple server class and client class. The client connects to the server and the server just echoes anything it receives. If I run the program over command line and specify the key store and trust store it works fine, but when I try to set the properties in the java code it seems to fail. I need to be able to set these are run time because it will be utilized in an Android program. If anyone knows what the issue is or knows of a better way to do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

I was asking if anyone knew why the SSL handshake was failing when I was running with the system properties set at run time vs as command line arguments to the VM. The problem was that the properties were not being set correctly.

Server:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket socket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(9999);
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) socket.accept();

InputStream input = sslsocket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

String str = null;
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.flush();
}
```

Client:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("localhost", 9999);

InputStream input = System.in;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw);

String str = null;
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(str + '\n');
    writer.flush();
}
```

Works fine:

```
$javac *.java
$java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore \
$-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit Server
$java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore \
$-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit Client < input
```

Does not work if set the properties at run time:

```
System.setProperty("-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/file/keystore");
System.setProperty("-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
// also set for the server (keyStore, keyStorePassword)

$javac *.java
$java Server; java Client < input.txt
```

It seems that it connects, but it when I actually type something into the console for the Client, it gives me the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1961)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
at Client.main(Client.java:38)
```

Comment: Re the close, I didn't vote 'unclear', I voted 'too localized'. It's perfectly clear what you're asking, but it's a trivial error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the system properties incorrectly.  The "-D" is a command line thing and not part of the property name.  Try:

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/file/keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

The way you have it coded, you are setting some bogus properties that are ignored by the SSL code.

Comment: Great, that seems to have fixed it. Thank you!